# How to use like query with datetime field in python

Tags: python, mysql

update_time is timestamp type in mysql. I want execute the following sql in python

```
select * from test_table where update_time like "%2017-05-11%"
```

and I write it in python like this

```
sql="select * from test_table where update_time like %s;"
cursor.execute(sql,("%2017-05-11%",))
```

It does get the result, but I also get the warning like this

```
Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '%2017-05-10%' for column 'update_time' at row 1
```

How to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add the first `%`,I think, so remove the first `%`, it won't return a warning:

```
cursor.execute(sql,("2017-05-11%",))
```

Actually, if you run this sql statement

```
select * from test_table where update_time like '2017-01-%';
```

It still returns warning , when you use `like` operator, you are actually making a string comparison . `update_time` will be converted to a string on-the-fly, so here's way to avoid this, you can use `cast` function:

[Cast Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

> Cast functions and operators enable conversion of values from one data
>   type to another.

e.g.:

```
select * from test_table where cast(update_time as char) like '%2017-01-%';
```

Works well and no more warnings. In fact, here's a better way, you can just use this to use **index**, date strings will be cast to **DATETIME** in this case,

```
select * from test_table where update_time between '2017-05-11 00:00:00' and '2017-05-11 23:59:59';
```